# My Bootstrap image grid is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've been doing my portfolio and right now I'm doing the skills section which consists of a 6 image grid of each skill logo. For this I'm using Boostrap and I'm having a problem with the second row. It just clusters in the middle different from the first row.  I'm linking my CodePen in case somebody can help me identify my problem.. (the idea of the CodePen is just watching the code as you guys can't see the images in there).

https://codepen.io/norwyx/pen/yLozjLg

Here's the HTML of the section that is not working:

```html
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="skills__first-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/html5-logo.png" alt="HTML5 logo" class="img-fluid" id="html__logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/css3-logo.png" alt="CSS3 logo" class="img-fluid" id="css__logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/js-logo.png" alt="JavaScript logo" class="img-fluid" id="js__logo"> 
  </div>
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="skills__first-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/html5-logo.png" alt="HTML5 logo" class="img-fluid" id="html__logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/css3-logo.png" alt="CSS3 logo" class="img-fluid" id="css__logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 skills__item">
      <img src="./images/js-logo.png" alt="JavaScript logo" class="img-fluid" id="js__logo"> 
  </div>
```

Comment: hi and welcome, closing row div are missing ;). It's a good practice to always indent your code. you would probably have spotted the issue directly

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. I'm going to correct it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the `d-flex` class from the row, bootstrap 4 and 5, row has already a flexibility, and the second thing is that if you want your images in the center of the `div` add class of `text-center` on each columns, your problem will be resolved

Comment: I'm going to try your solution and update you about it..

Comment: And how can I center them without using the text-center property? I don't like how they look. They are splitted by a lot, I'd rather having them closer to the middle